# Way to place two elements in single div like this

Tags: html, css

I want to place two divs side by side with the webpage being responsive. 
I implemented it using two divs similar to bootstraps col-md-6. but there must be a simpler way using class=btn. any kind of solution is welcomed.

[JSbin](http://jsbin.com/raxud/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="btn blue"></div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
    <div class="btn red"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cont{
     display:inline-block;
     width:50%;
     height:100px;
     background:#eee;
     padding:10px 5px;
     box-sizing:border-box;
}
.btn{
     width:100px;
     height:80px;
}
.red{
     background:red;
     float:left;
}
.blue{
     background:blue;
     float:right;
}
```

Comment: What's your actual goal? Your site is responsive. How do you want it to behave?

Comment: "Way to place two elements in single div like this" - like what?

Comment: @desperado i want two div.btn to be centered and side by side 
so had to use two divs.cont
but i want to place both div.btn in one div.cont and they have to behave in the same way as now

Comment: this looks like a "okay" solution to me. In practise div nesting is quite common and often needed. Check a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `display: flex` e.g. at http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I think it is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: How well is Flexbox supported?

Comment: Well. It seems like just yesterday we were all hoping it would get adopted. IE support (not less than 11 it appears) might be a no-go, but glad it got adopted.

Comment: In IE 10 use ms-flex ... Yes flexbox is very nice very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    .cont{
     margin: 0 auto; // added
     display:inline-block;
     width:50%;
     height:100px;
     background:#eee;
     padding:10px 5px;
     box-sizing:border-box;

}
```

Other Example:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 200px">
  <div class="inner1" style="width: 100px; float:left;"></div>
  <div class="inner2" style="width: 100px; margin-left: 100px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So is this what you mean?

HTML

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="btn blue"></div>
    <div class="btn red"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .cont{
        margin: 0 auto; // added from desparado
        width:50%;
        height:100px;
        background:#eee;
        padding:10px 5px;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    .btn{
        width:100px;
        height:80px;
    }

    .red{
        background:red;
        float:left;
    }

    .blue{
        background:blue;
        float:right;
    }
```

You can swap out margin auto for inline-block and play around by wrapping in an additional container.

Since you are giving a specific width to your buttons - by setting a width to your container and using margin width set to auto, I believe you get what you are looking for.